# Difference between form validation and data cleaning in DJango

Tags: python, django, django-forms

I have got the concept of form validations in DJango at basic level but I am struggling to get grip over what actually **cleaning** data in DJango means? What's difference between cleaning and validation ?

Comment: Have you read the docs https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/4.1/ref/forms/validation/?

Comment: Yes. But I didn't get the meaning of "clean". What is cleaned data ? or cleaning of data?

Comment: When form data is received by Django it's usually in a raw form like a string, cleaning is the process by which the raw data is converted to the correct type for the field (int for an IntegerField, datetime for a DateTimeField, model instance for a ModelChoiceField, etc.) - the cleaned data is then validated once it's the correct type

Answer (score 0):

- Django Provided `clean()` method for getting values from the fields and doing operations with it.
- lets me explain it.
- suppose I have one Form which is StudentRegistration(forms.Form)
  and have three fields (name, email, and roll_no).
- In Form API Django provide `clean_field()` and `clean()` method for validating data
- Here `clean_field()` or `clean()` method gets data from Form and after getting data from Form using
  `clean_field()` or `clean()` you can validate as per your requirement

#### ---------- EXAMPLE ---------------

```
class StudentRegistration(forms.Form):
    name=forms.CharField()
    email=forms.EmailField()
    roll_no=forms.IntegerField()

    # -------- DJango Validation [clean_field()] -------- validate using clean_field() method.
    def clean_name(self):
        name = self.cleaned_data['name']
        if len(name) < 2:
            raise forms.ValidationError('Name should be more than 2 character')
        else:
            return name

    # -------- Validate data using [clean()] method ------- validate using clean() method.
    def clean(self):
        cleaned_data = super().clean()
        valname=self.cleaned_data['name']
        valroll_no=self.cleaned_data['roll_no']
        if len(valname)<2:
            raise forms.ValidationError('Name should be more than 2 character')
        if len(roll_no) == 0:
            raise forms.ValidationError('Roll number should be gater than 0')
```

#### You can also validate data in views like this.

```
def InsertData(request):
    student_data = Student.objects.all() # Show data of Student Table
    if request.method == 'POST':
        form = Student(request.POST,request.FILES)
        if form.is_valid():

            name = form.cleaned_data['name']
            roll_no = form.cleaned_data['roll_no']
            if len(name)<2:
                print("Name should be more than 2 character")
            if len(roll_no) == 0:
                print("Roll number should be gater than 0")

            form.save()
            messages.success(request,'Student Successfully Inserted')
            return redirect('/home/')
    else:
        form = Student()
    context= {'form':form,'student_data':student_data}
    return render(request,'home.html',context)
```

##### In short here role of cleaned_data, clean(), and clean_field() methods is to get pure data from Form which is entered by the user, and do some operations with it.

##### Here I put code for all methods of Form validation which provided by Django

```
# -------- DJango Validation [clean_fieldname] -------- validate using clean_field() method.
def clean_name(self):
    name = self.cleaned_data['name']
    if len(name) < 2:
        raise forms.ValidationError('Enter > 2')
    else:
        return name

#-------- DJango Validation [ clean() ] -------- validate using clean() method.
class StudentRegistration(forms.Form):
 name=forms.CharField()
 email=forms.EmailField()

 def clean(self):
    cleaned_data = super().clean()
    valname=self.cleaned_data['name']
    valemail=self.cleaned_data['email']
    if len(valname)<4:
        raise forms.ValidationError('Name should be more than or equal 4')
    if len(valemail)<10:
        raise forms.ValidationError('Email should be more than or equal 10')


#-------- DJango Validation By [Built-in Validators] -------- validate using Built-in Validators.
forms.py
form django.core import validators
from django import forms
class StudentRegistration(forms.Form):
    name=forms.CharField(validators=[validators.MaxLengthValidator(10)])
    email=forms.EmailField()

#-------- DJango Validation By [Custom Validators] -------- validate using Custom Validators.
form django.core import validators
from django import forms

def starts_with_s(value):
 if vaule[0] != 's':
    raise forms.ValidationError('Name should start with s')

class StudentRegistration(forms.Form):
 name=forms.CharField(validators=[starts_with_s])
 email=forms.EmailField()
```

Comment: But broadly speaking, which activity happens first? Is it validation followed y cleaning or the other way? If possible, please justify your answer.

Comment: Yes,is_valid() method follow clean or cleaned_data

Comment: First activity is clean data and.then after we can apply appropriate validation with fields and then finally is_valid() method checks our validations